# how to make an ionic framework state routing?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to both angularJS and the ionic framework. I know that the ionic framework uses the angularJS way of thinking, but also has its own features. I am learning from tutorials (among them: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/using-ui-router-navigate-ionicframework/). I created a new ionic project which is blank (ionic start projectName blank). I modified the app.js-file to now have;

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('test', {
           url: '/test',
           templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
           controller: 'testController'
           });
    console.log("hello I am in config");
});
```

below the .run information. I created a template folder, which is in the wwww-folder. In the test.html file, I wrote;

```
<ion-view ng-controller="testController" title="U">
    <ion-content> text </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How can I now either; call upon the testController to show the test.html content in the index.html-file or show the state ("test") in the index.html?

Comment: If you need some help on StackOverflow best is to include a plnkr/fiddle/codepen with your code and explain here where you get stuck. Could you please add a plnkr/fiddle/codepen? Also the Ionic tabs is a great way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote you made a `template` folder. However, your folder should be named `templates` (notice the letter **s**) since you used that in the `templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',`.

You don't actually "show" the state in index.html file. Instead, when you navigate (using your browser) to you app (best to do with `ionic serve`) and try to append to the link the following url `/test` (so it would look something like http://127.0.01:8100/#/test) you should see the content of `templates/test.html`.

But, as Mark Veenstra noted, for any further help we would really need you to make a CodePen example.

Comment: @all. thank you. I will soon make a codePen example.